# JS/jQuery event does not fire after addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I'm using a script that creates an HTML structure like this by adding objects with JS and jQuery using createElement and appendChild:

```
<div id="divLayer">
    <div id="divBox">
        <!-- stuff -->
        <div id="btnSave" class="button small">Save</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Elements positions are respectively *absolute*, *absolute* and *relative* and displays are *block*, *block* and *inline-block*.
I have defined an array that contains objects attributes like this:

```
var objects = {
    divLayer: {
        tag: 'DIV',
        id: 'divLayer',
        parent: 'body'
    },

    divBox: {
        tag: 'DIV',
        id: 'divBox',
        parent: '#divLayer'
    },

    btnSave: {
        tag: 'DIV',
        HTML: 'Save',
        id: 'btnSave',
        parent: '#divBox',
        events: {
            click: function () {
                alert ( 'Clicked' );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part where I create objects and add listeners to them:

```
for ( var config in objects ) {
    var object = document.createElement ( config.tag );

    ...Setup other attributes...

    for ( var event in config.events ) object.addEventListener ( event, config.events [ event ]  );

    $ ( config.parent ).get ( 0 ).appendChild ( object );
}
```

Graphically everything's correct. I can see divLayer on the background, divBox over it and btnSave, inside the box and every attribute is correctly compiled but, when I click the button nothing happens.
If I put the button directly on divLayer it works.

Where am I doing wrong?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Perhaps a CSS issue where `<!-- stuff -->` is overlapping your button. Try changing the `z-index` of the `btnSave` to a high number.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the order of enumeration is never guaranteed when using `for-in`. Your code relies on each new element being added to the DOM before the next one is processed in the order you defined. JavaScript does not guarantee that this will happen. An Array would be better. `var objects = [{ ... }, { ... }, { ... }]`, then `for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from using an Object where an Array would be safer, you're trying to access a property on `config`, but `config` is just a string representing the property name.

You need to use `config` to get the value.

```
for (var config in objects) {

    var obj = objects[config]; // get the object

    var object = document.createElement(obj.tag);

    object.id = obj.id;  // set the ID

    for (var event in obj.events)
        object.addEventListener(event, obj.events[event]);

    $(obj.parent).get(0).appendChild(object);
}
```

Also, you're leaving out some code, so I can't tell if the other properties are being set correctly. I added the ID, and now your code works.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/yBN6V/

Answer (score 0):

Try binding using jQuery itself, delegating the event to a static parent:

```
for (var event in config.events) 
    $(document).on(event, object, config.events[event]);
```

I've bound the event to `document` in that example, you should really use the closest non-dynamic element which is available on page load.